# Matplotlib displaying histogram with a specific value on x and y axis

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

value = [8904,8953,8977,9147,9243,9320]
bin = np.arange(0,70,10)
ax.hist(value, bins=bin)
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

I am trying to plot a histogram with the value array on the x-axis and the y-axis will be the bin. But when I run the code I get an empty chart. Could anyone please help me out. Thank you

Comment: This is because your values are outside of the bin range. there are no values in the range (0,70), and, as a result, all the bins are empty. Also, make sure you have commas in your list definitions

Answer (score 0):

First thing I see is that in your values array, your data points aren't separated by commas.

Second thing, your values are outside the ranges of your bins. All your values are well into the thousands, and your bins' range is between 0 and 70.

Here is my edited version of your code (I included my import statements to make things clear). I changed the values to being within your bin ranges:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

value = [7, 8, 15, 45, 50, 80]
bin = np.arange(0,70,10)
ax.hist(value, bins=bin)
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

The result I get is [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22bWk.jpg), which illustrates what's going on. The data point 80 is outside the bin range, and therefore isn't shown at all, just like the data points you originally had. Other than that, all data points are shown in the histogram.

Hope this helps!

Edit: you said in a comment to this answer that you want it to be horizontal, not vertical. You add `orientation="horizontal"` to your ax.hist statement as an argument. New code looks like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

value = [7, 8, 15, 45, 50, 80]
bin = np.arange(0,70,10)
ax.hist(value, bins=bin, orientation="horizontal")
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

Your plot should now look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYsDV.jpg).

Comment: I get your solution but what i want is the values to appear on the y-axis whiles the x-axis should be bin.

Comment: That sounds like you're just looking for `plt.bar`, then?

Comment: @NartRazak ah, I get you. Add the argument `orientation="horizontal"` to your ax.hist statement. The new statement will be `ax.hist(value, bins=bin, orientation="horizontal")`

Comment: @NartRazak did I give you what you needed?

Comment: Yeah, this will work for me thank you very much really appreciate it. My other question is how can I change the values on the x-axis.